# Why should I use Zerigo Managed DNS with my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I'm starting a project using Rails and have bought a domain with Dreamhost. I've already deployed it to Heroku and now just need to take care of the DNS at Dreamhost to point my address to Heroku. Heroku recommends we use Zerigo. Why should I used Zerigo for DNS management rather than doing it manually myself? What are the long-term and short-term pros and cons of using Zerigo?

Please share you're opinions or experiences.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zerigo gives you some added whizz such as CNAMES on Apex records.

More information can be found here: http://neilmiddleton.com/the-dangers-of-a-records-and-heroku/

Comment: thanks. the comments at the bottom are great too! will go with Zerigo.

Comment: Do they actually have CNAMES on Apex records? or do they just respond with a 301 MOVED to *www*.example.com when you ask for example.com?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the pricing model from [DNSimple](https://dnsimple.com/r/83637b79c39db8): $8/month for 10 domains or $18/month for 50 domains. They offer much of the same functionality but are cheaper for 10 domains. They also and don't charge you based on DNS request volume. While on Zerigo, I would see unusual spikes in DNS requests and get footed with the bill. It eventually got to the point where the Zerigo was significantly more than the $18/month plan on DNSimple so I switched.